# Laptop screen upgrade

Tags: laptop, displays

I have a HP 15s-dy 3501TU laptop, whose screen is only HD and resolution is 1366 by 768 resolution. Is it possible to upgrade it to a full HD IPS display panel with 1920 by 1080 resolution? It is currently using AU0 3191 display (which is factory default). I have searched many forums, some of them says yes, while other said its absolutely impossible. I have asked a spare parts supplier same question, he said yes, it is possible. So my question is:

- Is this really possible to upgrade this laptop to a full HD display?
- If yes, Am I able to update its graphics driver to appropriate resolution, because the current highest resolution is 1366*768?

Comment: Is it possible, probably yes. Is it so hard that you shouldn't even try it? Also yes. For the GPU driver, that gets the native resolution of the panel and gives that as max resolution

Comment: @Irsu85 it has only integrated intel hd graphics, no graphics card. can i expect the graphics driver to detect that current resolution has been changed and update accordingly?

Comment: MESA does that automatically, I don't know for sure with the Windows drivers though, but that should also do that automatically